# Create a dataframe with and specific name within a function depends on input

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, function

I need to create a dataframe with and specific name within a function depends on input.

Here is my code:

`

```
def filter_season (df_teams ,season):
    
    df_teams[season]= df_teams[df_teams['SEASON']== season ]
    return df_teams[season]
```

`

Error got: ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 34, placement implies 1

I expect a result where the dataframe is created with a name due to the condition said in the funcion.
ex:
filter_season(df_teams, 22) #(Refers to season 2022)

OUTPUT:
df_teams_22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, use [`varname`](https://pypi.org/project/varname/) with [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/functions.html#globals) :

```
def filter_name(df, season):
    sub_df = df.loc[df['SEASON'].eq(season)].copy()
    globals()[nameof(df) + "_" + season] = sub_df
```

And here is an example to give you the general logic.

```
import pandas as pd
from varname import nameof

df = pd.DataFrame({'character': ['cobra', 'viper', 'sidewinder'],
                   'max_speed': [1, 4, 7],
                   'shield': [2, 5, 8]})
​
print(df)
    character  max_speed  shield
0       cobra          1       2
1       viper          4       5
2  sidewinder          7       8
```

Now, let's apply our function to return a new dataframe with a custom name (based on the filter).

```
def filter_name(df, charname):
    sub_df = df.loc[df['character'].eq(charname)].copy()
    globals()[nameof(df) + "_" + charname] = sub_df

filter_name(df, "viper")
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df_viper, type(df_viper))

  character  max_speed  shield
1     viper          4       5 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```